# Spring MVC: How do I forward to a specifc page after a successful Login?

Tags: spring-mvc, view

New to Spring MVC, I am trying to forward to a specific page of my application after I login.

How do I do so?

Is it using the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using spring-security you can map it in the target url

Something like -

```
   <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/denied"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/home" />
```

This post cover it in detail.

http://www.journaldev.com/2736/spring-mvc-security-example-using-in-memory-userdetailsservice-and-jdbc-authentication

Comment: with spring security this should be in spring-security.xml

Answer (score 1):

Use @RequestMapping annotation to forward to specific pages. So in a Controller class you'd have something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showMainMenu(
        UserBean user, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "login";
    }
    try {
        loginMethod();
        return "menu";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(Where loginMethod() is a method from another class where your login logic resides). And the controller forwards to the /menu URL upon successful login or stays on the /login page if there are errors upon the login attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You may just redirect to some different request mapping after successful login.

```
  if(successfulLogin){
    return "redirect:../abc/differenturl";
    }
```